# What's the style called for these recruitment posters?

Tags: illustration, style-identification, posters

I'm looking for the correct terms to use when I'm going to request the printing of a poster for a white wall and I just want to have enough information for communicate to the designer/lithography company<sup>1</sup>.

| Image | Links |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [source](https://www.pinterest.com.mx/pin/766456430329884599/) and [original link](http://crystalclearart.blogspot.com/2008/02/gears-of-war-propaganda-posters.html) |
| [image] | [source](https://www.pinterest.com.mx/pin/115334440453541622/) |
| [image] | [source](https://www.pinterest.com.mx/pin/some-locust-propaganda--121878733635986540/) |

In my own words, these posters looks like vintage recruitment vintage posters - but, to be honest and not disrespectful, almost *anything* nowadays is called "vintage" and I lack knowledge about design to describe it past this. It kind of reminds me of the *Bioshock* video game series.

These images act as an encouragement to keep fighting, cheering up the spirit of the combatants.

I've tried search on Google typing: `<insert game name here> + poster` and picking the images I like - with no particular inclination to any specific *type* of design, but, I don't know if there is a more specific term for search *propaganda-like* posters with gaming thematic - like ***Gears of War***, in this case.

---

<sup>1</sup> I searched on the internet about posters and I found "displate.com" and I want one poster for my room, but, I'm not really sure how to describe the type of design I want - also I said "lithography", because that's the term I get once I search on Google by typing (*in Spanish*) "print poster bogotá" and I got this page - https://www.pixelart-impresion.com/producto/posters - here is where I'm thinking to make my request for a poster/cartel and hopefully get a good outcome/product - I don't even know if the poster to be printed/made will be metallic or how I'm going to set it on the wall, so, any advice/guidance are more than welcome.

Comment: Just a note here. "Cartel" means something completely different in English.  It's a false friend. These are just called "posters" in English.

Comment: @BillyKerr you're correct. In Spanish it's also used the term "afiche", because the "cartel" word has the other meaning as well. Thank you for your feedback 

Comment: One thing to note is how much realism you'd like the poster to have. Your examples happen to go from more realistic to less realistic (more cartoon/flat). That would be helpful information for the illustrator/designer

Comment: A search for "vintage video game recruitment poster" gets you a lot more of similar results

Comment: @ZachSaucier that's a good search term to use. I'll used it. Thank you. About the realistic aspects, I have no idea how to define more aspects, but, I'll keep in mind your feedback if I pick for pay for the creation of a customized design. For now, I'll see what's available online and send it to print. Much appreciated 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styles *rarely* have any *specific* name - they are most commonly just described.

I would describe these as "**pseudo WWII Eastern European propaganda posters**", reminiscent of [**German propaganda**](https://www.google.com/search?q=WWII%20German%20Propaganda&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1828&bih=1241&ei=TLOCZNLYKP3V5NoPibmGqA4&iflsig=AOEireoAAAAAZILBXKl3_734WbBbp6vlQpG9dPYez0vO&ved=0ahUKEwjSrpKjtbX_AhX9KlkFHYmcAeUQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=WWII%20German%20Propaganda&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6BQgAEIAEOgYIABAIEB46BwgAEBgQgARQAFiJHmCVIGgAcAB4AIAB4AGIAb8hkgEEMi0yMJgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img) or [**Russian propaganda**](https://www.google.com/search?q=russian%20WWII%20propaganda&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1828&bih=1241&ei=1rWCZM7rFNig5NoP04y2qAI&iflsig=AOEireoAAAAAZILD5hRn9Wr-lfbyuJxUXcuu-WuD5IVy&ved=0ahUKEwjOrvfYt7X_AhVYEFkFHVOGDSUQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=russian%20WWII%20propaganda&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQ6CAgAEIAEELEDOgQIABADOgYIABAIEB5QAFiQImDXI2gAcAB4AIABnAKIAYslkgEEMi0yMpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img) during that timeframe. But that's merely *my* description.

---

For what it's worth, "Lithography" is a printing *technique*, not an art style. *Any* art style can be reproduced via lithography. - Similar to describing a meal as "fried", i.e. it doesn't tell you anything about *what* the meal is.

Comment: and this is why AI software need to call a style by the artist name that most prominently display that style.